# How to add flights to Cortana's notebook?

Tags: cortana

I've an upcoming flight, SK 4788, on 1/9. It seems she didn't recognize the ticket that was sent through email to my Microsoft account.

How do I manually add a flight to Cortana's notebook? Also, on a specific date in the future?

Comment: I had a flight that didn't show up for a day or two after i received the email.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**, you can add flights manually to Cortana's notebook.

To add it, ask Cortana for the flight status for your flight. For example, ask Cortana for "status for flight NY 130" and she will show you the status. You'll have the option to add the flight to Cortana's notebook. Once added, you can change the date for the flight to track flight further away in the future.

[image: Simply ask Cortana for the status of your flight.]
[image: She will show you the status and also allow you to add it to the notebook (Show XX XXX updates)]
[image: The flight will appear under Interests in the notebook]
[image: If you tap the flight in the notebook you'll be able to change its date to another one in the future]

Comment: Horrible how you have to specifically add the word "status", otherwise it won't pull it up. Doing "ny 130 status" is enough. Idk why they can't detect it with just "ny 130". Also "status ny 130" won't work...

Answer (score 5):

Cortana may already be tracking your flight. In the Cortana app, make sure you have the *Detect tracking info, such as flights, in messages on my phone* selected.

In addition, your airline must include schema.org formatted metadata in the email for the flight information.

Cortana also doesn't show you your flight information in it's main ui section until you are nearly ready to depart, as of today, your flight is more than a week and a half out, it will not show you a visual cue until probably the day before. However you can dig into Cortana's notebook to see what is being tracked in the travel section.

Comment: To back up @caschw's answer, [this is how to format emails with the correct Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn632191.aspx). If Cortana isn't detecting them, your airline might need a refresher... send them that link ;)

Comment: You're actually wrong. Please see my answer.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder Thanks for pointing out some of the details I had missed. I updated my answer.

Comment: Do I need to read the email from the airline on the phone or otherwise interact with it?

Comment: @KateGregory I just had flight info pop in Cortana's notebook before I actually opened the email.