# Cortana Flight Tracking. Within what amount of time will Cortana automatically track a flight?

Tags: settings, cortana

I have an upcoming flight, in two weeks. The flight information is not available online as of yet. I have already received a confirmation email. Will Cortana still save my flight, once the information is available? Will I have to automatically load it into my notebook?

Comment: Did Cortana track this flight for you? if so, you should be able to answer your own question, if only with a "at least" quantifer

Answer (score 1):

Cortana can manually track flights that depart within a month.

If you're sent a confirmation email that contains [schema.org markup](http://schema.org/FlightReservation) for the information, then Cortana will [save the flight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn632191.aspx), otherwise you'll have to [tell her to track the flight](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/7459/how-to-add-flights-to-cortanas-notebook) yourself.